# Can COM be made to support overloaded methods?

Tags: com, atl

I want to create a COM component which has two interfaces one derived from another which I know is possible in COM. But I wanted to know whether using one interface derived from each other can somehow get around the limitation of not being able to use overloaded methods? For instance

```
interface IMyInterface : IDispatch {
     [id(1), helpstring("method OverloadedMethod")] HRESULT OverloadedMethod(BSTR someName);
}

interface IYourInterface : IMyInterface {
   [id(1), helpstring("method OverloadedMethod")] HRESULT OverloadedMethod(BSTR someName, LONG someParam2);
}
```

Thanks in advance,
-Neel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Overload resolution is entirely a compiler implementation detail.  At its core, COM is entirely agnostic of what methods are named.  All it knows is a GUID that identifies an interface and a table of jump addresses that point to the methods that implement the methods.

On the upper end, this is taken advantage of in WinRT for example.  An api that's COM based at its core.  The language projections for C++/CX and .NET *do* support WinRT method overloads.  This is possible most of all because WinRT uses a more advanced way to *describe* the interface.  The .winmd file format uses the same metadata format as .NET and is capable of describing method overloads.  Backed by a more advanced version of the IDL syntax that allows adding annotation to map the raw method to an overloaded method name.

But that's future-music in most COM scenarios, like the one you describe.  A compiler used by the programmer that writes the client code to use your [ComVisible] assembly will use the type library that you generate from your assembly.  Either with Tlbexp.exe or the Regasm.exe /tlb option.  The .tlb file format is very old, dates back to 1996 and was originally designed to be used by Visual Basic.  It cannot describe method overloads, VB didn't support them either back then.

Long story short: no.